# Simple lines using line.new from version 4 Need to turn them off using an input

Tags: pine-script

```
EL20H = line.new(bar_index[3], LAG_LOW_L20, bar_index[0], LAG_LOW_L20,  width = 5, color=#FF0000)
line.delete(EL20H[1])
```

This is simply drawing a horizontal line for the last three bars of the chart at the level defined by `LAG_LOW_L20`

I set an input to turn this off: 
// if LSC 
// label.delete(LAG_LOW_L20)

I have made multiple changes in response to compile error messages.  There must be a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

This:

- Will turn the line on/off using the script's *Inputs*.
- Only starts plotting the line on the realtime bar for more efficiency.
- Instead of constantly drawing and then deleting the line, it draws it once and then uses `line.set_*()` to change the line's attributes than need to be changed. This also makes the code more efficient.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
LAG_LOW_L20 = highest(10)[1]
LSC = input(true)
if LSC and barstate.islast
    var EL20H = line.new(bar_index[3], LAG_LOW_L20, bar_index[0], LAG_LOW_L20,  width = 5, color=#FF0000)
    line.set_xy1(EL20H, bar_index[3], LAG_LOW_L20)
    line.set_xy2(EL20H, bar_index[0], LAG_LOW_L20)
```